# UIViewController do not call dealloc in ARC project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In an ARC project, I `addObserver` for a notification in `viewDidLoad:` and `removeObserver:` in `dealloc`. But after I pop the viewController, `dealloc` is not executed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refreshData)
                                                 name:MyNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"==================");//There is nothing print out.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MyNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this may perhaps you have enabled nszobie objects, disable them. i don't know why but if nszombie enabled in arc, dealloc is not invoked.

go to product>edit schems> unchek the enable zombie